# Display one active menu at a time

Tags: angular

How do I go about displaying a navigation sub-menu one at a time using a directive or other recommended way?

The user should be able to click any menu which should close any other active menu

The issue I am trying to get around is removing the .active class from the other child li elements first?

```
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li appExpandMenu class="site-nav-item active">Menu 1 ...sub menu options</li>
    <li appExpandMenu class="site-nav-item">Menu 2 ...sub menu options</li>
  </ul>
</nav>


import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appExpandMenu]',
})
export class ExpandMenuDirective {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostBinding('class.active') isOpen = false;

  @HostListener('click')
  toggleOpen() {
    // todo remove .active class from all other li elements
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to check https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive before doing anything, I don't think you need any complicated logic for that

Comment: a directive should not care about its siblins... maybe you intended to create a component instead?

Comment: I am using RouterLinkActive for active paths,its working well, but for toggling menus with click events not sure how this helps the above situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can listen to `mouseout` event in your directive and close the menu assuming that the menu doesn't have to persist when the mouse cursor moves out.

If not then directive is overkill for your requirement. Something trivial like the following should do it

Component:

```
private classActivate = 'active';
private menus = [ 'submenu1', 'submenu2', 'submenu3', 'submenu4' ];

public onMouseUp(event) {
  const id = event.currentTarget.id;
  for (const menu of this.menus) {
    if (id === menu) {
      this.toggleActivation(event.currentTarget);
    } else {
      this.deactivate(event.currentTarget);
    }
  }
}

private toggleActivation(target: Element) {
  if (target.classList.contains(this.classActivate)) {
    target.classList.remove(this.classActivate);
  } else {
    target.classList.add(this.classActivate);
  }
}

private deactivate(target: Element) {
  if (target.classList.contains(this.classActivate)) {
    target.classList.remove(this.classActivate);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="submenu1" class="site-nav-item active" (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)">Menu 1 ...sub menu options</li>
    <li id="submenu2" class="site-nav-item" (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)">Menu 2 ...sub menu options</li>
    <li id="submenu3" class="site-nav-item" (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)">Menu 3 ...sub menu options</li>
    <li id="submenu4" class="site-nav-item" (mouseup)="onMouseUp($event)">Menu 4 ...sub menu options</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I went with the component approach, passing in the router.isActive flag into a function to help with the toggling of menu items and using [ngClass] to toggle the css classes